# checking if character is in string Python

Tags: python

```
from decimal import *
errors = "abcdffghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz?><:;\|{}[]"
purchase_price = Decimal(input("Please enter the price of your item"))
while purchase_price in errors:
    print("Please enter the price of your item ex: 123.45")
    break
else:
```

I'm having trouble checking if a character or characters in the  errors var is being input.

When input is anything that is not a number

The Output is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/Tax Calculator/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    purchase_price = Decimal(input("Please enter the price of your item"))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

If a character is there I would like to write a loop to give them another opportunity to to re-enter the price.

Comment: Why Decimal? Convert the input to float do like this, `float(input("Please enter the price of your item"))` It would cause an error if illegal char is entered

Comment: sailesh, just thought I'd note again that floats are not a good way to handle money, since usually good accuracy is important :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input to be a number, I'd suggest making it a float and handling the exception if you cannot parse it:

```
try:
    purchase_price = float(input("Please enter the price of your item"))
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    pass # wasn't valid, print an error and ask them again.
```

Though, please note that floats are not a good way to accurately handle money! This is a huge deal! You need to search online to find a good solution: http://code.google.com/p/python-money/

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I've got the money library up and running in place of Decimal. Could you explain the except portion for me? I got lost when I saw  `as e`

Comment: That passes the exception object to `e` so you can properly log and handle the exception as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import *

def ask():
    input_str = input("Please enter the price of your item");
    try:
        number = Decimal( imput_str )
        return number
    except( InvalidOperation, ValueError, TypeError ) as e:
        return ask()


number = ask()
```